# WooCommerce checkout button missing

Tags: button, woocommerce, checkout

I am using Oxygen Theme (Laborator) with WooCommerce. I also use a plugin called “Woocommerce German Market” to use the Shop in Germany.

Until yesterday, when I updated the theme, everything worked fine. But now my checkout button is missing. When I go to checkout page, there is no button to continue. You can check on my page: http://th16580w23.vorschauseite.eu/

I already checked with the plugin support – it seems to come from different not standard named strings? The problem does not occur with other themes.

I really hope you can help me with this. I really need this.

Comment: Why not check with theme support? If it doesn't occur with other themes, then the problem is likely in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it it's working fine.